# MIPS - why cant you load address from a register that has been stored using load immediate?

Tags: assembly, mips

i don't understand why this isn't allowed and raises errors?

Here is a code sample

```
    .text
main:
    li $a2, 4
    li $a0, 5
    li $v0, 1
    # print 5
    syscall
    li $a0, 4
    li $v0, 1
    #print 4
    syscall
    # Why does these three lines below which are commented out cause an error?
    #what this part should do is print 4. Instead throws an error
    #lw $a0, ($a2)
    #li $v0, 1
    #syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

This code was made just so i can understand why you cant lw from a register that has been initialised?(not sure if thats the right word) using li

Comment: You can, assuming it has been initialized with a valid memory address. `4` is unlikely to be valid. Note, that would not print `4` even if it worked, it would print the content of memory at address `4` (since `lw` reads from memory). Not to mention the argument shouldn't be in `$a2`.

Comment: im not sure what you mean? the code throws an error

Comment: It throws an error because `lw` tries to read from memory at address `4` and that is an invalid address.

Comment: i fixed the typo thanks for the heads up